# pandas dataframe get NaN when mapping

Tags: pandas, csv, dictionary

Can anyone answer me why I always get NaN ?[image]

[image]

Comment: Title name updated

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some whitespaces, so is necesary remove them first.

You can check it by:

```
print(Xtrain['Sex'].head().tolist())
```

So use:

```
Xtrain = pd.read_csv('train.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
Xtrain['Sex'] = Xtrain['Sex'].map(sex_mapping)
```

Or:

```
Xtrain = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
Xtrain['Sex'] = Xtrain['Sex'].str.strip().map(sex_mapping)
```